# I need to populate a form when I click on a dropdown. Which option is more performant?

Tags: javascript, php

I can either:

-Get the information using AJAX, creating a request every time I click on the dropdown.

-Populate the form passing the information to div like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<div id="name_{{$item->id}}" value="{{$item->name}}"></div>
<div id="date_{{$item->id}}" value="{{$item->date}}"></div>
...
@endforeach
```

And then setting the value of the form with javascript, making a single request that extracts all the information and passing it to the site.

I have already done both, but I would like to know which one would be the most performant.

Comment: How many `$items` do you have?

Comment: so the second is just a template that's called only once? can you give more details about the second one?

Comment: @MoshFeu Between 1 and 400 and each item consists on 6 tables

Comment: @Edwin The second one is just passing the info to divs so I can use Javascript to put the information from these divs into the form client-side.

Comment: but is loaded only once, or? and the ajax one every time when you push the dropdown box. Right?

Comment: @Edwin Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is both, but depends on the case.

For instance if you use the ajax method and the dropdown box is never pressed is better than the passing the values.

If the dropdown box is hit once or more than once, the second method will be better. But you will have also a downside: you'll not get the newest version of the dropdown box information from where ever you get it.